# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdf5 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for hdf5

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to poretools and need to install hdf5.  I have tried

> $ pip install hdf5

and get

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdf5 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for hdf5

my echo $PATH is:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/salt/bin:/usr/local/sbin

and $which python gets me:

> /usr/local/bin/python

I suspect that there is some issue with PATH as this mac originally had anaconda and python 3.x installed and I had to remove the anaconda from the PATH string.

Answer (score 2):

HDF5 is not a package on pypi.org. You would usually install this with a system package manager for the libhdf5 package. You may need to install Homebrew on your Mac to get this package. Anaconda has an HDF5 package and can make this easier. The h5py package is a Pythonic interface to the HDF5 binary data format. You can find the installation steps here, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html. The simple way is to use the preconfigured installation with Anaconda, Canopy, or PythonXY. The docs show how to do this with Pip which still requires you to get libhdf5 with a system package manager.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped significantly.